# Add and remove entries from database 

Tags: database, jsp, dictionary, javabeans

The following code is from my addRemove.jsp 
The purpose it serves is to have to forms, one for submitting a new word to the word table of my database, and one to remove one. To add a word, one must complete the germanName, gender and englishName. Upon submission, the user is able to see the updated table.

Below that, I created a remove form where the user must specify the germanName value in order to remove the word. the button should direct the user again to the updated table. the problem is that only the first submit button redirects me. Furthermore, it seems that the removal doesn't occur at all. I will only provide the addRemove.jsp but I could also post the WordDataBean.java file if you think you need to take a look at it as well.

addRemove.jsp

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<%-- beans used in this JSP --%>
<jsp:useBean id = "word" scope = "page"
             class = "org.me.jsp.beans.WordBean" />
<jsp:useBean id = "wordData" scope = "request"
             class = "org.me.jsp.beans.WordDataBean" />

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Student Registration Form</title>

        <style type = "text/css">
            body {
                font-family: tahoma, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            }

            table, tr, td {
                font-size: .9em;
                border: 1px groove;
                padding: 2px;
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <jsp:setProperty name = "word" property = "*" />

        <% // start scriptlet

                    if (word.getGermanName() == null
                            || word.getGender() == null
                            || word.getEnglishName() == null) {

        %> <%-- end scriptlet to insert fixed template data --%>

        <form method = "post" action = "addRemove.jsp">
            <p>To add a new word complete the form below</p>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>German name</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type = "text" name = "germanName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Gender</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type = "text" name = "gender" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>English Name</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type = "text" name = "englishName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan = "2">
                        <input type = "submit"
                               value = "Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <% // continue scriptlet
              } // end if
              else {
                  wordData.addWord(word);

        %> <%-- end scriptlet to insert jsp:forward action --%>

        <%-- forward to display word list --%>
        <jsp:forward page = "wordListView.jsp" />

        <% // continue scriptlet

                    }  // end else

        %> <%-- end scriptlet --%>

        <% // start scriptlet

                    if (word.getGermanName() == null
                            || word.getGender() == null
                            || word.getEnglishName() == null) {

        %> <%-- end scriptlet to insert fixed template data --%>

        <form method = "post" action = "addRemove.jsp">
            <p>To remove word complete the form below</p>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>German name</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type = "text" name = "germanName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan = "2">
                        <input type = "submit"
                               value = "Remove" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <% // continue scriptlet
              } // end if
              else {
                  wordData.removeWord(word);

        %> <%-- end scriptlet to insert jsp:forward action --%>

        <%-- forward to display word list --%>
        <jsp:forward page = "wordListView.jsp" />

        <% // continue scriptlet

                    }  // end else

        %> <%-- end scriptlet --%>


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI:  Any time you find yourself putting Java code into a JSP page, you should consider that a "code smell."  It's a bad practice.  You should study the "Model View Controller".

Answer (score 0):

There is serious problem to your logic.

According to

```
if (word.getGermanName() == null
       || word.getGender() == null
       || word.getEnglishName() == null) {
```

If value any of the three is NULL then it will show form to add. If not then it will addword using `wordData.addWord(word);` and then forward to `wordListView.jsp`. So, this works fine with add.

Now, Again you are checking all same three fields for `null` and based on the same showing form to remove (i.e. on Text box). In your case of remove button first condition (which you meant for add) will be true and it will show the same form with 3 input fields.

Comment: I agree with that, this is the part that I'm getting wrong there, so what should the condition be and how exactly should I form this for the remove table?